# Salesforce1 take picture option in android not available

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

I have a visualforce page on which one button is shown of name upload photo. What i want is, when user clicks on button there should be a pop up of name take picture.

In iOS it works perfectly, it gives two by default options 
1) choose from existing
2) click a new picture

In android it gives option of gallery only but i want option of take picture also.

Kindly help.

Comment: Are you testing this on a real device or an emulator? Are you sure the 'device' you are testing on has a camera app installed? The Android intents system will only show you options from apps that exist on the device.

Comment: Yes, I am testing it on real device. Also it has camera app installed. But still facing same problem. Any other trick or option.?